# Trim( remove zeroes at the boundaries ) RGB Matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, matlab-deployment

I have a RGB matrix like this:

```
      0  0  0    0  0   0   0    0
      0  0  23   0  0   0   0    0
      0  1  255  0  0   130 22   0
      0  49 0    0  0   0   120  0
      0  0  0    0  79  0   213  0
      0  0  0    0  0   0   0    0
```

Need to trim(remove zeroes at the boundaries) this matrix to be like:

```
      0  23   0  0   0   0  
      1  255  0  0   130 22
      49 0    0  0   0   120
      0  0    0  79  0   213
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `sum` to find rows and columns which are all zeros. Then, remove them.

```
s1 = find(sum(mat,2)>0);
s2 = find(sum(mat,1)>0);
mat([1:(s1(1)-1) s1(end)+1:size(mat,1)], :) = [];
mat(:, [1:(s2(1)-1) s2(end)+1:size(mat,2)]) = [];
```